# Accessing ndarray and discarding invalid positions - Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have one question about accessing a matrix position that in fact does not exists.

First, I have an matrix with **rows** rows and **cols** columns. From this matrix, I have to get sets of **n** x **n** sub matrices. For example, to get 3 x 3 sub matrices, I do the following:

```
for x, y in product(range(1, matrix.rows-1), range(1, matrix.cols-1)):
    bootstrap_3x3 = npr.choice(matrix.data[x-1:x+2, y-1:y+2].flatten(), size=(3, 3), replace=True)
```

But, as can be seen, I'm not considering the extremes, and I have to. For x = 0 and y = 0, for example, I should consider `matrix.data[x:x+2, y:y+2]` (the center should be the current x and y), returning a `3 x 3` with the first row/column = 0.

I know that I can achieve this with some **if** statements. But I guess Python should have a clever way to do this properly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442570/how-to-get-the-neighboring-elements-in-a-numpy-array-with-taking-boundaries-into also helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a new matrix, padded with `(n-1)/2` zeros around it:

```
import numpy as np

rows, cols = 4, 6
n = 3
d = (n-1)/2
data = np.arange(rows*cols).reshape(rows, cols)
padded = np.pad(data, d, mode='constant')
for x, y in  np.indices(data.shape).reshape(2, -1).T:
    sub = padded[x:x+n, y:y+n]
    print sub
    bootstrap_nxn = np.random.choice(sub.ravel(), (n, n))
```

This assumes `n` is odd, and that the submatrix *center* is always within the the original `data` matrix.  If `n` is even, the *center* of the submatrix isn't well defined.

If you actually want to have the submatrix overlap with the data matrix with only one row, then you'd need to pad with `n-1` zeros (and in that case even vs odd `n` won't matter).