# Python Numpy Array geht values of neighbours

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, neighbours

I want to get all neighbour values of a np.array.

The array looks like:

```
x = np.array([  [1, 2, 3, 4 ],
                [5, 6, 7, 8],
                [9, 10, 11, 12],
                [13, 14, 15, 16] ])
```

What I have is:

```
i = 2
j = 2

n = x[i,j-1], x[i,j], x[i,j+1], x[i-1,j], x[i+1,j], x[i-1,j-1], x[i+1,j+1], x[i+1,j-1], x[i-1,j+1]
```

This returns (what I want)

```
(10, 11, 12, 7, 15, 6, 16, 14, 8)
```

But also got bugs for example when i want the neightbour values of

```
i = 3
j = 3
```

That gives:

```
Exception has occurred: IndexError
index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4
```

An other soultion is:

```
def find_neighbors(m, i, j, dist=1):
    return [row[max(0, j-dist):j+dist+1] for row in m[max(0,-1):i+dist+1]]
```

and

```
n = find_neighbors(x, i, j)
```

Which gives me an array of the neightbours but also gives me not all neightbours when I set

```
i = 0
j = 0
```

because it only gives me:

```
[array([1, 2]), array([5, 6])]
```

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550302/find-neighbors-in-a-matrix.

Comment: I think this solution is even more pythonic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442570/how-to-get-the-neighboring-elements-in-a-numpy-array-with-taking-boundaries-into.

Comment: What would the desired result for `i=3` and `j=3` be?

Comment: @VasilisG Should be

```
[16, 13, 15, 4, 1, 3, 12, 9, 11]
```

@dome I saw them but they didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of python indexing wrapping around for negative indices.

```
def wrap_nb(x,i,j):
    return x[np.ix_(*((z-1, z, z+1-S) for z,S in zip((i,j), x.shape)))].ravel()
```

This requires `i` and `j` to be nonnegative and less than the shape of `x`.

If that is not guaranteed:

```
def wrap_nb(x,i,j):
    return x[np.ix_(*(np.r_[z-1:z+2]%S for z,S in zip((i,j), x.shape)))].ravel()
```

Examples:

```
>>> wrap_nb(x,1,-2)
array([ 2,  3,  4,  6,  7,  8, 10, 11, 12])
>>> wrap_nb(x,0,-1)
array([15, 16, 13,  3,  4,  1,  7,  8,  5])
>>> wrap_nb(x,0,0)
array([16, 13, 14,  4,  1,  2,  8,  5,  6])
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the solution! I will have a look on this when I get back home!

Answer (score 1):

```
# function to find the start row and column
def find_start(x):
    start = x-1 if x-1 >= 0 else 0
    return start

# function to find the end row and column
def find_end(x, shape):
    end = x+1 if x+1 <= shape else shape
    return end

def find_neighbors(a, i, j):
    neighbors = []
    row_start, row_end = find_start(i), find_end(i, a.shape[0])
    col_start, col_end = find_start(j), find_end(j, a.shape[1])

    for y in range(a.shape[0]):
        for z in range(a.shape[1]):
            if y >= row_start and y <= row_end:
                if z >= col_start and z <= col_end:
                    neighbors.append(a[y][z])
    return neighbors

i, j = 0, 0                    
neighbors = find_neighbors(a, i, j)
print(neighbors)
```

Output: `[1, 2, 5, 6]`

```
i, j = 3, 3                    
neighbors = find_neighbors(a, i, j)
neighbors
```

Output: `[11, 12, 15, 16]`

```
i, j = 2, 2                    
neighbors = find_neighbors(a, i, j)
neighbors
```

Output: `[6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16]`

This would cover all the edge cases.

Comment: I set the "a" to an "x" i your code and I can confirm you output. Thank you!

But maybe I don't understand the function but I need for 

`
i = 0
j = 0
`

This output:
`
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 13, 14, 16]
`

Comment: @Pablo `i = 0, j = 0` is the first element and it should have only 3 neighbors. One on its right -> 2, one on its bottom -> 5 and one on its diagonal -> 6. So output will contain 4 element (3 neighbors and one itself).

Comment: @Pablo if this solution worked, please accept the answer.

Comment: Thats right. But I need the others for my programm too :P

Comment: @Pablo I can understand you have requirement but to solve a problem we must have some pattern. It's ok if you want those numbers but problem for me  is, on basis of what logic you derived those numbers. Because there must be some logic or pattern so we can apply that on whole array to make our results consistent. But if we talk about true neighbors, then this solution covers that. If you still want to satisfy your requirements, you can open a new question but please mention some pattern or logic to extract the result.

Comment: You are right. The quest is to simulate a experiment where n x n people paint there home with a color randomly choosen from the colors of the neighbour houses. for example I got j=2 and i=2 in a 4 x 4 array then I have 8 neighbours. 4 have a red colored home, 2 green ones and 2 yellow ones. My own home is colored pink. So the propabbility that I paint my home green is 2/9.

What we expect is that when every neightbour do this at the same day in a year the homes will be painted in one unique color after a period of time.

The restriction from this exercise is we look at all neightbours.

Comment: So I may be not very logcial but in this exercise it is the restriction..

Answer (score 1):

I got the following solution form an mate:

New array:

```
homes = np.array([  [1, 2, 3, 4 ],
                [5, 6, 7, 8],
                [9, 10, 11, 12],
                [13, 14, 15, 16] ])
```

Code for returning the neighbour values:

```
neighbour  = []                                          
neighbour  += [homes[i][j]]                              # value itself
neighbour   += [homes[i][(j + 1) % n]]                   # value right 
neighbour  += [homes[i][(j - 1) % n]]                    # value left
neighbour  += [homes[(i + 1) % n][j]]                    # value down
neighbour  += [homes[(i + 1) % n][(j + 1) % n]]          # value right down
neighbour  += [homes[(i + 1) % n][(j - 1) % n]]          # value left down 
neighbour  += [homes[(i - 1) % n][j]]                    # vlaue up
neighbour  += [homes[(i - 1) % n][(j + 1) % n]]          # vlaue right up
neighbour  += [homes[(i - 1) % n][(j - 1) % n]]          # value left up
```

Which returns me:

```
i = 0
j = 0

[16, 13, 15, 4, 1, 3, 12, 9, 11]
```

Thats what I need but I'am still interessed in solution like the one from Abdur