# How to create a mask filter with a 3x3 matrix

Tags: python, matrix, filtering

I would like to pass a 3x3 matrix mask to each of the elements of a larger matrix.

The 3x3 matrix would have this conformation:

```
Mask = [(,,),
        (,,),
        (,,)]
```

If any negative value is found in the bigger matrix, this value must be replaced by the average of the other eight numbers in the mask matrix.

Example:

```py
A = [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
     (3, 3, 1, 1, 1),
     (4, 5, -1, 3, 1),
     (1, 2, 2, 7, 3),
     (1, 2, 2, 7, 3)]
```

Result = mean (3, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2, 2, 7) = 3

Can anybody suggest how to do this in python?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7442570/11659881) has some relevant answers for extracting the surrounding elements of an element in a matrix. Then you'd simply want to compute the average of all the positive elements in that subset to perform your replacement.

Comment: This sounds similar to image morphology.

Comment: For clarity: what if the first element of the first row was negative? In that case, would you choose your mask to be a 3x3 matrix comprising rows 1-3 and columns 1-3, or would you instead choose the 2x2 in the top left corner comprising rows 1-2 and columns 1-2?

Comment: What do you do in situations where there are two adjacent `-1`s? Or if there are many `-1`s? Unless you impose a constraint that there are no more than one `-1`s within 3x3 windows, you might need to add additional information on how to handle 2-9 `-1`s within a window.

Comment: In situation where there are two or more adjacent negative value, I would try pass the filter, and if still remain problems, try to pass again.

Comment: For a first negative element, I would like to use a 3x3 filter with only 3 values in it to do the avarege (sounds like a 2x2).